# What does it mean " there was no finer boy anywhere."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the Harry Potter book, the author said:

> The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.

I didn't get the idea of the last sentence "there was no finer boy anywhere".

Comment: Look in a dictionary for adjective "fine", and try to find one of the definitions that fits this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means here that Dudley was the best child they could imagine. If you know the Potter series, you know that "finer" here is ironic. Dudley is far from fine, in nearly all of the senses you'll see in the dictionary.

Comment: It has nothing to do with their imagination. As given, it simply means that, in their opinion, he was the finest child they had encountered.

Comment: True, true. My bad. The Dursleys had no imagination.